# Dynamic number of input text fields on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I need to do an HTML/JS project that does the following:

1. A blank HTML page contains an text input field for integer input
   (let's say no higher than 30).
2. After that I need to create on the HTML page as many text input
   fields as I entered in the first input, so, for example, if I input
   20, I have 20 new input text fields below my initial input text.
3. I need to be able to process these 20-like input fields in JS,
   for example, get their values by their id's, etc.

I have no trouble doing step 1, but have no idea what to use for steps 2 and 3.

Can I do it in plain JavaScript or should I start looking at some frameworks? Angular? React? Anything else?

I'm baffled by all these fancy framework names and logos but I don't understand what I need.

Comment: Try something then come back...

Comment: I would suggest doing it in plain JavaScript. Once you feel comfortable, you can move on to frameworks.

Comment: You can also do that by jquery instead of angular or any other frameworks as I thought there is no need to use angular or any other frameworks for this simple thing the basic idea of angular is two way bindings and many more so it's not valid to use angular for this

Comment: And if I do it in plain JavaScript, do I need to understand DOM for that?

Comment: Well you'll need to interact with the DOM. So you'll start understanding as you do it.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery) and [this](http://www.jqueryfaqs.com/Articles/Dynamically-add-and-remove-TextBoxes-and-get-value-of-dynamic-TextBox-using-jQuery.aspx) hope it helps

Comment: You also don't need jQuery, but you can use it if you want.

Comment: He could probably achieve this using A) Opening new browser window, or B) Sending to different page with GET data in the URL. Some `for`/`while` loops will come in handy for this, in either way.

Comment: I doubt angular or jquery or any framework or library can create a blank page containing an input element?

Comment: @alekscooper Read [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) on how to create new windows, and writing to them. Then, come back with some code ;)

Comment: I will guys, thanks )

No, I'm not planning to use PHP for processing post/get submission. I'm going to do the whole thing in HTML/JS. Anyway, I'll hit the books/docs tomorrow and I guess I see the direction I should follow, so thanks :)

Comment: @alekscooper I put an answer down that covers everything. I tested in an `about:blank` tab, because JSFiddle doesn't support some stuff in there, but it should work like a charm.

Comment: The OP should change their question to not be asking for a framework/lib, but rather questions about their code. The hold explains this best. Just take out the last two sentences/paragraphs about frameworks/libs.

Answer (score 3):

This can be simply achieved using JavaScript DOM, via creating a new window. First, you check the input value, then use that value to create the input boxes.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" id="number" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
var newWindow = window.open("", "_parent");
newWindow.document.write("<form>");
for(i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    newWindow.document.write('<input type="text" id="box' + i + '" />');
}
newWindow.document.write("</form>");
```

That code will output the number inputted in textboxes. Each textbox will have a unique ID, such as "box1", "box2", etc.

You don't need any frameworks/libs for this, you can just use vanilla JavaScript, like above. jQuery does help, sometimes, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should try some code before ask !

I think you need something similar to this

```
function func() {
    var para = document.createElement("input");
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    var count = document.getElementById('stack').value ;

    if (count < 30) {
            while (count > 0){
            element.appendChild(para);
            count -= 1;
            }
    }else{
        alert("No more than 30 !");
    }
}
```

---

```
<body id="div1">
<input type="number" id="stack">
<button onclick="func()">Do</button>
</body>
```